# using a global variable on C#

Tags: c#, variables, static, global, void

So I have to use this `void`

```
static void PerformOption(int option)
```

However I want this `int` option to be able to be used by other `void`s as well.
I know this could be done by deleting inside of brackets and assigning a `static int` but I have to use `int` option for this `void`, so I cannot change this one.

So how can I make option as global variable?

Comment: your question is void,  please try again :)

Comment: If you want the argument to be used by other methods, then it all depends how your methods are organized. If those methods are called by this method, then keep passing this as arguments to others. If they are called seperately, then make this argument as global/class member.

Comment: You can create a static int and assign `option` to that static int inside `PerformOption` but I am almost certain that there is a better way to implement whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class MyGlobalsBecauseImEvilAndLoveBadProgrammingMemes
{
   public static int Spaghetti { get; set; }
}
```

then in PerformOption do

```
MyGlobalsBecauseImEvilAndLoveBadProgrammingMemes.Spaghetti = option;
```

but hopefully you want a member,  then do

```
  public class MyClass
    {
       int Option { get; set; }
       public void PerformOption(int option)
       {
          Option = option
          // other stuff
       }

       public void SomethingElse()
       {
         if(Option == 1)  // use Option at will
         {
         }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global `int` variable to hold `option` value inside the `PerformOption` method to be used in other methods.

```
public static class MyClass
{
     private static int globalOption;

     public static void PerformOption(int option)
     {
          globalOption = option;
          ...
     }
}
```